# Can the Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri be used to create URL strings with special encode?

Tags: php

I'm looking into ways to minimize/remove JavaScript scripts by providing pre-encoded strings to be used for HTML attributes.

Questions:

- What kind of string encode does the `Uri::getInstance('URL')->toString()` outputs?
- Can the `Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri` class be used to create equivalents of the `encodeURIComponent` JavaScript method and/or the PHP `rawurlencode` function?